# AS3 object passed as e.target does not match identical object passed through its array index

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, oop

I'm designing an inventory system. right now, I need to test whether or not an item is in the inventory in order for the stage to know whether to instantiate that item in the particular level or not.

I add the items to the levels in groups, so this code is located within an array loop which "unloads" the "pack" of items corresponding to each level.

```
if (inv.indexOf(group[i]) == -1) {
    //add item + item functionality
}
```

This method works when I add the item to the inventory such as this:

```
inv.push(group[i]);
if (inv.indexOf(group[i]) == -1) {
    //add item + item functionality
}
```

But that doesn't work, because why would I add an item to the inventory without the user collecting it first? so the code is actually structured as so:

```
            if (inv.indexOf(group[i]) == -1) {

                //if item is not in inventory, add to stage
                addChild(group[i]);

                //when a user clicks this (any) item,
                group[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function itemFunctionality(e:MouseEvent){

                    //target item clicked
                    var item = e.target;
                    //add the item to the inventory
                    inv.push(item);
                    //sidenote: if i were to check inv.indexOf(item) here, i 
                    //would get a positive index. unfortunately,
                    //i cant check whether the item is in the inventory
                    //after its already been added to the level...

                    item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemFunctionality);
            });
            }
```

The problem is when you leave and come back to the level, the items you already collected re-instantiate. If you collect an item again, the inventory adds a copy of the item you already collected.

The `inv.indexOf(group[i])` checker doesn't understand that when the array loop reaches the corresponding, `item group[i] ==` the object added to the inventory through `inv.push(item)` or in other words `inv.push(e.target)` (which, of course, I couldn't write directly into the code)...

When I trace whats inside of static array `inv`, what `group[i]` is within the array loop, or what `e.target` is, they all output the same type of item, "[object itemName]", signifying that the indexOf check SHOULD match up.

**Update :** 
It appears if I make the items static as well as the array group they belong to this method works within the mouse event callback:

```
inv.push(item);
group.splice(group.indexOf(item), 1);
```

Though I had to remove the items and the item groups from their own class and put them inside of the level class itself... I feel this method kind of sucks because everything is getting disorganized and grouped into the same class.

Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you mean under "leave and come back" but as I understand you're trying to check whether an DisplayObject is in the array inv. And this approach will not work. You need to add an ID for each item, in other words your level should be built with respect to some Model. In this model you can describe what items are present on the level, what are already connected. It's a problem of design of  your application, not the language.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are matched with their references. It means two objects created from the same class are not identical, they are different objects.

Assign unique IDs to your items and use them in your inventory. Like;

```
inv.push(item.id);
if (inv.indexOf(item.id) == -1) {
    //add item + item functionality
}
```

Working with IDs is also better for serializing / deserializing.

Answer (score 2):

There's your problem:

> The problem is when you leave and come back to the level, **the items you already collected re-instantiate**.

Why would coming back to a level cause reinstatiation of any kind?

You should only ever once create each level object and part of that process should be creating all objects contained in that level. Visiting a level merely is an interaction with that object, which may include removing objects and adding them to the inventory. Once the objects are gone from the level, they are gone.

There's no reason to reinstantiate a level (or any of the objects within it) when revisiting it. If you are running into this problem because you are using a time line based approach with frames and `gotoAndStop()` to switch between levels then this is the core of your problem and you should stop doing that.

Comment: im not using timeline code, but i am re-instantiating the levels when you travel between them. when you leave one level, it deletes itself and tells the stage to create a new instance of the level you're traveling to... i can see how this is a bad design choice now, lol. how else would i go about it?

Comment: im thinking of putting every location on the stage and changing their coordinates to accomplish this...but i feel this method is too clunky...will it slow down the game?